# Using Ti.Media.VideoPlayer video does not loop on iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, ios7, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

Having a weird problem with my app.

Trying to play a video in a loop (see the code below). VideoPlayer `repeatMode` is set to `Ti.Media.VIDEO_REPEAT_MODE_ONE`.

Works in simulator, works on iPhone 4s, works on iPad Air... does not work on **iPhone 4** (all of them running iOS 7.1.1 apart from simulator - 7.1).

**Exact symptoms:** after one play, video should restart from beginning, but it stops. If controls are available, I can press play to start playing it again, then after reaching the end it stops again.

I could swear that it worked on iPhone 4 before the 7.1 upgrade, but somehow it stopped.

Anyone could replicate this issue? Or have any idea?

Sys info:

- Titanium SDK: Tested with 3.2.3.GA; 3.2.2.GA; 3.2.1.GA; 3.2.0.GA
- Platform & version: iOS 7.1.1 (11D201)
- Device: **works** on iPhone 4s, iPad Air, simulator; **fails** on iPhone 4
- Host Operating System: OSX 10.9.2
- Titanium Studio: 3.2.3.201404181442
- Xcode: 5.1.1 (5B1008)
- Alloy: 1.3.1

Code for basic Alloy project to replicate:

`index.js`

```
var videoPlayer = Titanium.Media.createVideoPlayer({
    autoplay : true,
    fullscreen : false,
    mediaControlStyle : Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_DEFAULT,
    repeatMode: Ti.Media.VIDEO_REPEAT_MODE_ONE,
    scalingMode : Titanium.Media.VIDEO_SCALING_ASPECT_FIT
});

//Video is 12s long so it is easy to notice that it does not loop.
videoPlayer.url = "video/candles.mp4"; 
$.index.add(videoPlayer);
$.index.open();
```

`index.xml`

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some research and played around with the `Titanium.Media.VideoPlayer` and managed to work around the issue. Below you can find the solution in case anyone else encounter this problem.

First of all, some info on the problem.

I have found some forum boards where developers were having very similar problem with `MPMoviePlayerController` on iPad 1st gen. Looped video was less or more randomly freezing on loop. So I think there is a problem with the Apple video player on some devices, and not necessary with Titanium implementation.

My first approach was to try replay video on `complete` event that is fired when video stops playing, instead of using `repeatMode`.

So far so good. It worked on the first time, yay! But the happiness was rather short. During an hour of test of `videoPlayer.play()` on event `complete`, the video sometimes was repeating 10-30 times fine and then suddenly was freezing. What gives? Turns out the video player had some sort of a hiccup.

Normal sequence of events was as follows:

- video ends, `playbackstate` changes to 2,
- `complete` event is fired
- I restart video on complete
- `playbackstate` changes to 1, video is playing until the end.

For a mysterious reason once in a while this sequence got additional something happening:

- video reaches the end - `playbackstate` changes to 2,
- `complete` event is fired.
- video gets restarted on complete
- `playbackstate` changes to 1, video starts playing
- suddenly `playbackstate` changes to 1, video stops, without firing `complete` event.

**Solution**

So, knowing all this, I have set up listeners to listen to `playbackstate` instead of complete and when I hear `playbackstate: 1` then I restart video and tadaaa! Everything works!.

**Caveat:** not 'everything' unfortunately. I am using custom video controls, so I have lost pause, and stop ability (every time video playback state changes to 'stopped' I restart it forcefully). To make it work I have to remember to remove listener every time I press 'pause/stop' buttons and then reattach it afterwards.

Hope that helps someone.